# Where can I find Data set for Machine Learning purposes?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, data, sampling

I am currently doing a research in the attempt to detect onset sign of mental disorders through facial recognition. In order to do that, I would need training dataset which contains 1. Pictures 2. Diagnosis. Are there any open datasets that I could find/apply to? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. I am intrigued by your research question.  Are you suggesting that mental health diagnoses can be made by reading facial cues?

Comment: Personally identifiable information (like faces) coupled with mental health records? Seems ethically questionable, to say the least. The data set you are imagining would be a privacy nightmare. I think you're probably out of luck with this one, sorry.

Comment: To add to steveLangsford's comment, depending on where you are located it could be *illegal for you to do this research without approval by a regulatory body*.

Comment: Your best bet might be to find a researcher who already has such dataset collected and try to form a collaborative relationship with him/er where you help them analyze the data. For privacy reasons, it might be very difficult to find such data publicly posted online. To help build such relationship, try searching: https://academia.stackexchange.com/